# How to underline task when click on it and it should be saved to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.7

I am making todo webapplication.Suppose when user double click on his task it should be marked as completed and should be saved to database

Tried but didn't worked and it is not saved in database

```
<script>

    // Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
    var list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName === 'li') {
            ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
        }
    }, false);
</script>


            <div class = "card-body text-center">
                <h4 class = 'card-text'>Today</h4><hr><br>
                @foreach($task as $tasks)
                    @if($tasks->remind=='today')
                        <ul class = "list-group">
                            <form action = {{ route('task.destroy',$tasks->id) }} method="post">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <li class = "list-group-item ">{{ $tasks->task }}<span><button><i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:12px;color:red"></i></button></span></li>
                            </form>
                        </ul>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

When user double click on his task it should be underline to indicate completed and it should be saved to database also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, u need explain you mean.

- Show list task of user
- catch event user click into task
- push id task to server and update status this task

next step:
**u need catch click event**
you code HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click_to_task" data-task-id="1">Task 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="click_to_task" data-task-id="2">Task 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="click_to_task" data-task-id="3">Task 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="click_to_task" data-task-id="4">Task 4</a>
```

you JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.click_to_task').click(function () {
                let task_id = $(this).attr('data-task-id')
            })

        })
    </script>
```

Now: u have task_id. u will push this to server and update this task status
Using ajax

```
let url = '{{ route('update-status-task') }}'
         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"save.php",
            data:{task_id: task_id},
            success:function(data){
              // you process
            }
          })
```

Ok. now on server u just update status of tast to **Done** 
:D

Comment: how to save on server without using ajax

Comment: u just call URL with paramter is task_id when click to task.
http://hihi/update-task-status/{ Task_id }
=> on server. update status task to done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://codepen.io/Khadembd/pen/xxKPoBV

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".done").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).next("span").html();
    savetodolist(value);
  })
  
})

function savetodolist(val){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"todolistsave.php",
    data:{item:val},
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family:arial;
}

.todolist, .todolist li{
  list-style-type:none;
}

.todolist{
  padding-left:0;
}

.todolist li{
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  padding-left:30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position:relative;
}

.todolist li [type=checkbox]{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:200;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.todolist li span:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid rgb(24, 78, 163);
  border-radius:50%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.todolist li span:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:5px;
  height:10px;
  border-right:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  top:4px;
  left:7px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.todolist li [type=checkbox]:checked + span{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}

.todolist li [type=checkbox]:checked + span:before{
  background-color:rgb(24, 78, 163);
}
.todolist li [type=checkbox]:checked + span:after{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="todolist">
  <li>
    <input class="done" type="checkbox"> 
    <span>Buy Oranges</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="done" type="checkbox"> 
    <span>Attend Skype Meeting</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="done" type="checkbox">
    <span>Meetup with Sabriya</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="done" type="checkbox"> 
    <span>Deliver gift to Dad</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```